# Boolean algebra gives rise to a ring

Tags: ring-theory, category-theory, boolean-algebra

There is a well-known result that every boolean algebra $(R,0,1,\land,\lor,\neg)$ can be made a boolean ring by defining $$x\cdot y=x\land y\qquad\text{and}\qquad x+y=(x\land\neg y)\lor(y\land\neg x)\,.$$
However the proof requires a lot of computation. For $R=\mathfrak{P}(X)$, there is a simpler argument. Namely, one can show that the bijection
$$\mathfrak{P}(X)\longrightarrow(\mathbb{Z}/2)^X\,,\qquad A\longmapsto\chi_A$$
sending a subset on the characteristic funtion defined by that set respects addition and multiplication. It follows that $\mathfrak{P}(X)$ is a ring and the above bijection is a ring-homomorphism.

**My question is: can one deduce the general statement about boolean algebras from the special case above?** This would work out, for example, if either

> Every boolean algebra embeds into the boolean algebra defined by a power set.

or

> Every boolean algebra is a quotient of the boolean algebra defined by a power set.

The first of these conjectures would be in the same spirit as Cayley's theorem (or Yoneda's Lemma), the second would be in the same spirit as a polynomial ring (or free objects in general). Both techniques can be used to find identities in algebraic structures: To check that $(xy)^{-1}=y^{-1}x^{-1}$ holds in groups, it would suffice to check this in symmetric groups or in free groups.

However I know very little boolean algebras and I'm not able to check, if there is a way like this to avoid the computation, and if it is, which of my conjectures holds.

**Edit:** The answer by rschwieb suggests that my first conjecture is true, using some non-trivial ring theory and the equivalence of boolean algebras and boolean rings. So my question becomes: **Is there a simple way to write down an embedding  $(R,0,1,\land,\lor,\neg)\longrightarrow(\mathfrak{P}(X),\emptyset,X,\cap,\cup,X\setminus-)$ of boolean algebras?** Perhaps $X=R$ would be a good choice, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The natural embedding is given by taking $X$ to be the space of Boolean algebra homomorphisms from $R$ into the Boolean algebra of order $2$, equipped with what is essentially the Zariski topology. This is part of the proof of the Stone representation theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_representation_theorem_for_Boolean_algebras

Comment: Thank you, Qiaochu. Put in elementary terms, this is $$r\longmapsto\left\{f\colon R\to\{0,1\}\mid f(r)=1\right\}\,,$$correct? I will try to show this is a boolean algebra homomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

I think the theorem that you might be looking for is this:

> **Theorem**: A (commutative) von Neumann regular ring is a *[subdirect product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdirect_product)* of fields.

Then

> **Corollary**: A boolean ring is a subdirect product of some number of copies of the field of two elements  $\Bbb F_2$.

Since you can naturally interpret an element of $\prod_{i\in I} \Bbb F_2$ as a member of $\mathcal{P}(I)$, I think this is a proof of your first conjecture.

Comment: Ok, using the equivalence of boolean algebras and boolean rings, this shows that every boolean algebra embeds into a boolean algebra of the form $\mathfrak{P}(X)$. But since this equivalence is, what I want to show, I still have to work out this fact without using any ring theory. I will see what I can do. Thank you so far.